# it takes too much time to insert 5000 record in mysql database using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp

I'm using jdbc, mysql-connector-java-8.0.20 and xampp as mysql server to insert 5000 record in database
I used [this link](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database) to test that, and here is the code that I tested with

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Random;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo", "root", "");
            // here sonoo is database name, root is username and password
            String sql = "insert into emp(name, age) values(?, ?)";
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int age = rnd.nextInt(60);
                byte [] name = new byte[30];
                rnd.nextBytes(name);
                ps.setString(1, name.toString());
                ps.setInt(2, age);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("taken time: " + (endTime - startTime));
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is:

> taken time: 315309

Comment: Move the `PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);` outside the `for`.

Answer (score 3):

First, and easiest, prepare the `PreparedStatement` **once** before the loop. Like,

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int age = rnd.nextInt(60);
    byte[] name = new byte[30];
    rnd.nextBytes(name);
    ps.setString(1, name.toString());
    ps.setInt(2, age);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Second, if that is still not fast enough, use batching. Like,

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int age = rnd.nextInt(60);
    byte[] name = new byte[30];
    rnd.nextBytes(name);
    ps.setString(1, name.toString());
    ps.setInt(2, age);
    ps.addBatch();
    System.out.println(i);
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

BTW, use `Arrays.toString(name);` (you're currently storing a hashcode).

Comment: Yep, batching can make a difference. @MuhammadSayed I would measure the result with and without it.

Comment: the loop is executed fast, but it takes too long in executeBatch

Comment: @MuhammadSayed First, these are the only options I'm aware of to speed it up (in the code). Second, how long is too long? Third, what kind of network exists between your endpoints?

Comment: taken time: 304307, I didn't get your third question